# Install Python version 3 side by side with version 2 in Centos 7

Tags: python

I have a CentOS 7 machine which already has Python 2.7.5 installed. Now i want to install Python version 3 also side by side without disturbing the original Python version 2. If i install with pip i fear that it would install version 3 on top of the already existing version.

Can someone please guide me how to do the same ? Also i have created a virtualenvs directory inside my installation where i want to create the virualenvs.

At present whenever i create any virtualenvs using the virtualenv command it automatically copies the Python version 2 installable over there.

I want my virtualenvs to contain version 3 and anything outside my virtualenvs should run with version 2.

Is this even possible.

Thanks a lot for any answers.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method I know is to add the IUS Community repo for Centos 7 (only the most common x86_64 architecture is supported). Then simply install the required Python3 version directly with `yum`, e.g. `yum install python36u`

Link: https://ius.io/setup

Installing anything from an unknown source is a risk. The IUS has a good reputation - see e.g.
https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories - but you must decide yourself if you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

For CentOS 7, we can use IUS Community repo

```
yum -y install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
yum -y install python36u
yum -y install python36u-pip
pip3.6 install numpy
```

So outside your virtualenv, default pip may install for python 2 not python 3.

For Python2 virtaulenv support python3, you can try:

```
virtualenv python2-bridge
source ./python2-bridge/bin/active
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3 <folder>
source ./<folder>/bin/activate
python --version && pip --version
Python 3.4.3
pip 8.1.2 from /home/centos/<folder>/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

Refer(
https://opsech.io/posts/2016/Sep/06/creating-python-3-virtual-environments-on-centos-7.html)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles upon this old thread: note that as of CentOS 7.7, python3 is included in the official repos, so you can just do

```
yum install python3
```

See https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-on-centos-7/

Answer (score -6):

You can simply `apt-get install python3` and then use `-p python3` while creating your virtual environment. Installing python3 will not disturb your system python (2.7).

Comment: The title of the post explicitly states that this is on Centos, cent os does not have apt